# how to insert without duplicate from one table into another

Tags: mysql

I tried to insert from one table into another and im having with the redundancy..
I came up with a query but every time when i execute it, It cannot deals with duplicate.
here's my query...

```
INSERT INTO balik ( balik_date, balik_time, balik_cardID, balik_status,balik_type) 
select current_date(), '00:00:00', L_CardID, 'BELUM BALIK', L_Type 
FROM logdetail t1 
LEFT JOIN balik t2 ON (t1.L_CardID = t2.balik_cardID)
WHERE t1.L_Type = 'IN'
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: How _would_ you like to deal with duplicates, and what columns are unique?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm) helpful ?

Comment: Joachim : those (balik_date, balik_time, balik_cardID) are my PK...i just dont want any duplicate data inserted in my balik table..pls guide me...thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Use  INSERT IGNORE instant of INSERT.

> Use INSERT IGNORE rather than INSERT. If a record doesn't duplicate an
>   existing record, MySQL inserts it as usual. If the record is a
>   duplicate, the IGNORE keyword tells MySQL to discard it silently
>   without generating an error.

OR

Check row count for unique field. If row exist don't insert or update.

OR

> Use REPLACE rather than INSERT. If the record is new, it's inserted
>   just as with INSERT. If it's a duplicate, the new record replaces the
>   old one:

Source for definitions [MySQL Handling Duplicates](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm)